# Tensorflow (Contrib.learn) KeyError when fitting model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm somewhat new to coding and very new to Tensorflow, but I've taken an online machine learning course, so I have some background and an example under my belt.

I am using the Contrib.learn module(?), which puts Tensorflow in a scikit-learn style experience for the user. Anyway, my data set is 20 columns of float64 values, and just over 2000 rows long. Each column is named. I setup my feature_columns with,

```
feature_columns = []
for i in X_train.columns:
    feature_columns.append(tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column(i, dtype=type(X_train[i][0])))
```

And then I instantiate my deep neural network model with,

```
classifier = learn.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10,10,10], 
                                 feature_columns=feature_columns, 
                                 n_classes=2)
```

So far, so good. Then I try to fit my model with,

```
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, steps=100, batch_size=32)
```

And I get a really deep Trackback that ultimately ends in,

```
KeyError: 'IQR'
```

which is the name of my 6th data column.

There isn't a lot of examples of people using Contrib.learn, and I'm guessing the few people who are using it aren't as clueless as I am. If anyone happens to know what it might be referring to, I could really use the help, since I'm basically out of ideas. If you need any more information from me, or if you want me to paste the whole Traceback, just let me know.

Thanks for your time!

edit: [Link to Traceback (via Pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/emtNXLyA)

Comment: Yes, please include the full traceback. If it's too large, you could have it on pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up ditching Contrib.learn and doing it "the hard way" using Tensorflow's core functionality to build a multilayer perceptron.

Pretty cool stuff!

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I tried reordering the column names, but always end up throwing exception for the same key. Ever tried to figure out what the problem could be?

Comment: No, sorry. It's been a while since I've used either. I'd recommend doing it with Tensorflow directly since that's what ended up working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Function throws as it looks for a feature `IQR` (which is defined in your `feature_columns`).

In order to use `predict` you need to do something like:

```
predicted_values = list(m.predict(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_test), as_iterable=False))
```

Where `input_fn` is the input function and `df_test` is Panda's DataFrame with required features

Hope this helps.